# Python - При неравенстве размерности матрицы программа выдает ошибку

Tags: python, массивы, матрицы

Если задаю одинаковые числа, программа работает корректно, но как только задам разную размерность массива, то тогда выдает ошибку: "list index out of range". 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    import random  
def creatArray():
    r = 0
    print('Input first index matrix: ')
    x = int(input())
    print('Input second index matrix: ')
    y = int(input())
    array = []
    for i in range(x):
        array.append([])
        for j in range(y):
            array[i].append(random.randint(0,100))
            r += 1  
    u=0
    print("Matrix: ")
    for u in range (x):
        print(array[u])
    colmn = 0
    colmnIter = 1
    maxm = 0
    for n in range(x):
        s = 0
        for m in range(y):
            s += array[m][n]
        print("%3d" % s, end=' ')
        if (maxm<s):
            maxm = s
            colmn += colmnIter
        else:
            colmnIter += 1
    print("\nMаксимальний стовпчик має суму: %3d\nI це стовпчик пiд номер %2i" % (maxm,colmn))   
creatArray()
```

что нужно сделать чтобы програмка не крашилась при вводе разных значений? пожалуйста, подскажите)

Comment: Если планируете работать с матрицами и векторами то возможно вам лучше воспользоваться библиотекой NumPy, к тому же она написана на Сях, что дает неплохую прибавку к производительности вычислений.

Comment: Полностью поддерживаю @ИгорьИгоряныч - иногда "прибавка к производительности" больше трех порядков...

Comment: вопрос решился, нужно было просто поменять местами M и N:
  for m in range(y):
            s += array[n][m]

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сделать разные переменные для длины и ширины, либо отказаться от них вовсе(что лучше) Вот:

```
import random  

def creatmatrix():
    x = int(input('Input first index matrix: '))
    y = int(input('Input second index matrix: '))
    matrix = []
    for i in range(x):
        matrix.append([])
        for _ in range(y):
            matrix[-1].append(random.randint(0, 100))
    print("Matrix: ")
    for row in matrix:
        print(row)
    tmax = (0, 0)
    for idx_row, row in enumerate(matrix):
        sum_row = sum(row)
        print("%s %3d" % (idx_row, sum_row), end=' ')
        if (tmax[1] < sum_row):
            tmax = (idx_row, sum_row)
    print('Максимальная сума столбца: %3d' % tmax[1])
    print('Индекс этого столбца: %2i" % tmax[0])   
creatmatrix()
```

`

Comment: Я благодарю за прекрасный ответ, вариант тоже работает.
Но решил свой вопрос так:
 
вопрос решился, нужно было просто поменять местами M и N: for m in range(y): s += array[n][m]